# Syntax error with query on access

Tags: sql, ms-access

```
    SELECT Surname, Firstname, Team_Name, PostCode, Winner, Date_Of_Game,
          Place_Of_GameFROM, tblPlayerProfile 
    INNER JOIN tblTeamDetails 
        ON tblPlayerProfile.Team_ID_Number = tblTeamDetails.Team_ID_Number 
    INNER JOIN tblMatchStatistics 
        ON tblTeamDetails.Team_ID_Number = tblMatchStatistics.Team_ID_Number
    INNER JOIN tblGameResults 
        ON tblMatchStatistics.MatchID = tblGameResults.MatchID
    WHERE (((tblGameResults.MatchID)=[FormsReport]![MatchFormReportD8]![Combo10]));
```

I'm having trouble

Comment: post your error please.

Comment: It's Access SQL. All joins past the first one need to be surrounded by `()`.

Comment: also you have no space before `FROM` `Place_Of_GameFROM tblPlayerProfile` --> `Place_Of_Game FROM tblPlayerProfile`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Place_Of_GameFROM tblPlayerProfile` -> `Place_Of_Game FROM tblPlayerProfile`

Answer (score 0):

Check out this query. You forgot to specify `FROM`.

```
SELECT Surname, Firstname, Team_Name, PostCode, Winner, Date_Of_Game, Place_Of_Game
     FROM tblPlayerProfile 
    INNER JOIN tblTeamDetails 
        ON tblPlayerProfile.Team_ID_Number = tblTeamDetails.Team_ID_Number 
    INNER JOIN tblMatchStatistics 
        ON tblTeamDetails.Team_ID_Number = tblMatchStatistics.Team_ID_Number
    INNER JOIN tblGameResults 
        ON tblMatchStatistics.MatchID = tblGameResults.MatchID
    WHERE (((tblGameResults.MatchID)=[FormsReport]![MatchFormReportD8]![Combo10]));
```